# Not all rows join successfully in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins, census

I have a shapefile of census tracts and a CSV file with information I want to join to them. The CSV I am using has 65 rows, each for a unique census tract. I am using the census tract ID number as the key. For example of one the census tracts has an ID values of "1013.02". However, whenever I run the join I only get 60 of the rows from the CSV file to successfully join. I tried converting both key columns to double/real but that did not seem to help. I also checked to see if there were any duplicate values and there are none. I was curious if anyone has experience with a similar problem in the past? I have included links to a google drive folder containing the data and the website where I downloaded the census data from.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eJpCWjaT7tHT6Vz5ML5gSYUeXKASPC6a?usp=sharing

https://www.census.gov/geo/partnerships/pvs/partnership21v2/st48_tx.html

Comment: Have you tried converting the IDs to an integer? It's just a guess, but I suspect that will work better.

Comment: The problem with changing them to integers is that the numbers after the decimal place are critical parts of the ID number. For example I have IDs like 1115.41 and 1115.42.

Comment: Would any IDs become non-unique if you just drop the period? So 1115.41 becomes 111541. Sorry, that's what I meant by integer, which was not very clear.

Comment: Multiply by 100

Comment: So changing the IDs to integers did not help. When I went searched through the attributes of the census tract shape file I found 5 duplicate rows and 9 of the census tract values I was given in my CSV file were not present at all. Is there a place you all would recommend I download census tracts for Texas and the associated data from? Is there a way I can post the data that I have been using on Stack Exchange?

Comment: I saved the data I have been using on google drive if anyone wants to try the join themselves. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eJpCWjaT7tHT6Vz5ML5gSYUeXKASPC6a?usp=sharing

Comment: I got the shape file from this website. https://www.census.gov/geo/partnerships/pvs/partnership21v2/st48_tx.html

Comment: "Is there a way I can post the data that I have been using on Stack Exchange?" Yes, upload it and update your post with the link to download the data.

Comment: The second link has too many files. Which ones are you working with?

Comment: Tarrant County is the data that I am working with as I am interesting in the area around Arlington Texas.

Comment: Please be more specific. I found 2 zip files, with lots of layers. Just upload the data you want to join to CSV file.

Comment: I just uploaded the census tract shape file by itself. Let me know if you see it now.

Comment: @IanMoffit, your link has dozens of layers again. Your question asks about one layer and one text table.  What is the name of the shapefile you're trying to join to the text table?

Comment: Let me try sharing the link again. I posted the file as a geojson. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eJpCWjaT7tHT6Vz5ML5gSYUeXKASPC6a?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem. This time I tried downloading census tract shape file from this website:

https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/tiger-line-file.2020.html#list-tab-LECU8DJGKIFM33SF8E

I then used GeoID as the key field for the join rather than the tract number.